# When dropdown menu selected fill textbox with data from database

Tags: php, ajax

I have a problem with my code. I am trying to fill a `textbox` with data from the database. It needs to show the price of the selected item in my `dropdownmenu`. But it is not working. I can fill my `dropdownmenu` but when I select an item in it, my `textbox` stays empty.

I am using the following table structure:

```
forms (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sort` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,
  `tax` int(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

// index.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM database";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<select class='form-control select2' id='product1' name='product1' onChange='getstate(this.value);' style='width: 100%;'>";
     echo "<option selected disabled hidden value=''></option>";
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                      echo "<option value='" . $row["id"]. "'>" . $row["name"]. "</option>";
     }                   
echo "</select>";
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();

?>
<html>

<!-- Your text input -->
<input id="product_name" type="text">

</html>

<script>
function getPrice() {

    // getting the selected id in combo
    var selectedItem = jQuery('.select2 option:selected').val();

    // Do an Ajax request to retrieve the product price
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'get.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: 'id=' + selectedItem,
        success: function(response){
            // and put the price in text field
            jQuery('#product_name').val(response);  
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        },
    });
}
</script>
```

get.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) ;
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error) ;
    } 
else 
    {
    $product1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) ;

    $query = 'SELECT price FROM forms WHERE id=" . $product1 . " ' ;

    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $query) ;
    if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) 
    {
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res) ;
            echo json_encode($result['price']);

    }
    else
        {
        echo json_encode('no results') ;
        }

    }
?>
```

Can someone help me to fix this?

Comment: where does `$product1` come from you seem to be setting `$productId`

Comment: `$product1` must be the right one, I changed it in the code. But it is still not working

Comment: you misspelled `fetch`

Comment: `$result = mysql_fecth_assoc($res);` should be `$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);`

Comment: Thanks, I changed it in my first post. But it still not working. When I change `. $product1 .` into `1` (ID) it shows me the right price for ID = 1. But when I run `index.php` with `. $product1 .` it doesn't work

Comment: I think there is no connection between `index.php` and `get.php`. How can I fix this?

Comment: change to `$product1 = (int) $_POST['id'];` for now, see if it works, if it does, focus on the function you are performing then

Comment: Maybe It can work. But I can not test it because there is no link between `index.php` and `get.php`. Get.php is showing "0 results". When I run index.php nothing is happening. The code that works in get.php is not working when I run index.php

Comment: You need to go over your code more carefully, I noticed another error. You have an `on change` action calling a function but that is not the same function name as the function your ajax request is in

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database;

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
    $productId = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

    $query = 'SELECT price FROM forms WHERE id=' . $product1;

    $res = mysql_query($query);
    if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
        $result = mysql_fecth_assoc($res);

       echo json_encode($result['price']);


}
?>
```

Whenever you are sending and receiving data it should be JSON encoded for AJAX to read your data, so die won't work as it is an asynchronous event and you should use json_encode in client side.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'get.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: 'id=' + selectedItem,
    success: function(response){
        // and put the price in text field
        jQuery('#product_name').val(response);  
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);
    },
});
```

For now response should work and for larger data like keys and value you should dump response `console.log(response)` and check obj keys values best practices

Comment: try  putting else statement in ur ur mysql_num_rows and see if that works

Comment: See my first post. I added an else statement. When it goose wrong it needs to show `echo "No results";`. But I even not get this message.

Comment: else {json_encode("no results"); u need to json_encode for response back

Comment: I changed it. See my first post. But when I run `get.php` I am getting a parse error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Connection' (T_STRING) in C:\Program Files (x86)\........\get.php on line 11`

Comment: This problem is solved. See my first post. But I think there is no connection between `index.php` and `get.php`. How can I fix this?

Comment: why no connection ur url is getting to get.php ur file structure should be inde.html and get.php should be on same dir